# Angular JS: encode url & replace browser history

Tags: angularjs

An array param, like this:

```
var paramArray = {page: 1, per_page: "10", shipperCompany: "s&g"};
```

I need to encode the paramArray.shipperCompany variable. In project, I use **$location.search** to build url.

```
$location.search(paramArray);
```

Then I looked for the comments of the angular js, got the result：

> If the argument is a hash object containing an array of values, these
>   values will be encoded as duplicate search parameters in the url.

This method will change search part when called with parameter, but I do not want the browser to save the last url and i wish replace it.

```
window.location.replace(url);
```

However, how can I meet these two points?

Comment: Eventually I solved this problem with ” $location.search(paramArray).replace(); ”

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I solved this problem with fellow code。

**$location.search(paramArray).replace();**

It works.